# Error getting window size on android: "The method getWindowManager is undefined"

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to get the window height and the weight.
I have this in my code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
width1 = metrics.widthPixels; 
height1 = metrics.heightPixels;
```

but I have an error:

> The method getWindowManager is undefined

what i should import for this?
or i can get the sizes of the screed in different ways?
i have imported

```
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
```

Answer (score 49):

Where are you using this code?

The error of the `getWindowManager` says that cannot find the method because the root of your class doesn't have it.

Try this:

```
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

or

```
((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
  .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

If this doesn't work, please paste your activity

Comment: Hi Shailendra, 
In my case I am using separate FramLayout over Keyguard Screen, in Android AOSP project, there is one Activity which is for main View and one Bouncer Class over that Activity, I need to resize of that bouncer view to Full.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
 display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
 display.getWidth(); // to get width of the screen
 display.getHeight(); // to get height of the Screen
```

**UPDATE**

Please review the [Android-Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#getheight) site. For more reference.

You can use below snippet of code to fetch height-width of the device.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Comment: getHeight() is now deprecated

Comment: @IgorG.: can you give me the link where it is said that it is deprecated ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Context` of the activity with `getActivityContext()`

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivityContext().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
width1 = metrics.widthPixels; 
height1 = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this for example if you are using it inside a fragment:

```
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are calling above method in an activity class, or outside activity.

For Wallpaper, this method is not availed to you to get height or width of window, you need to get width and height of available window by using surface.

Comment: no, i am doing a live wallpaper and i am calling this in the Engine of the wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
import android.app.Activity;

((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager)((Activity) getContext()).getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
```