# getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics) not working properly

Tags: android, android-screen

I'm using this code, to get screen size

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    //more stuff
    setTextSize();
}

private void setTextSize() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    //more code
    sometextview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, width/10); //example only
}
```

As it turns out, **in rare cases this doesn't work**. I'm setting some text size, and sometimes it doesn't resize text at all. I think it only happens whenever I haven't open application in a while, so it's very hard to debug it. Only idea I have is, that *this is asking for screen size before application even knows it* (it's the first activity). *How can I solve this?* This is the only method for getting screen resolution that I know that supports all APIs.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833825/get-window-size-on-android) (see the first answer)

Comment: It works the same, problem is it might be a few days before the "bug" happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ViewTreeObserver for this specific Textview.

Some code snippet.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = myTextView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                setTextSize();

            }
        });
```

The only thing you should be careful of is that this would be called repeatedly every time view changes, so you need to keep a dirty flag to track changes.